# Object.keys() returns object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I am having an issue with an Object that I try to get the keys from as an array. Here is the object on the picture below

```
{
  "archive": null, 
  "branchs_id" : "5",
  "code": "12344"
}
```

When I try to get only keys as an array with `Object.keys(object)` it return a list of keys but not as an array but object. What should I do? I really need this to be an array

```
let firstObject = response[objecType + 's'][0];

__this.setState({ attributes: Object.keys(firstObject)}, () => {
   __this.forceUpdate();
});
```

I cannot .map through my this.state.attributes here as it is an object and not an array

Comment: No image, code please.....

Comment: Arrays are Objects in JavaScript

Comment: @Mamun edited the question

Comment: please also add some code, not only logs.

Comment: @vibhor1997a edited

Comment: What does response[objecType + 's'][0] return ?

Comment: @Deshak9 it returns the object shown inside the first block of code of my question

Comment: `Object.keys` won't return object. I think that you are trying to access `this.state.attributes` before the asynchronous `setState` has completed.  Try `console.log(this.state.attributes)` in the `setState` callback and see if it's object or array..

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help.

```
for (var key in bookMarks) {
         console.log(bookMarks[key])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this doesn't work?

```
var obj = {archive: null, branchs_id: '5', code: '12344'};
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // ["archive", "branchs_id", "code"]
```

It seems it work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you need array kind of structure then you can you this code and in state you also use -

```
[obj].forEach(function(val) { console.log(val) });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` won't return object. I think that you are trying to access `this.state.attributes` before the asynchronous `setState` has completed.  Try `console.log(this.state.attributes)` in the `setState` callback and see if it's object or array..